# Sequence of errors leads to init failure and subsequent kernel panic

Tags: rhel, hardware, scsi

We have one Redhat test server installed on Vmware ESXI. And when I boot the server it gave this error.

[image]

How to solve this issue because due to this error it doesn't boot.

Comment: What is there to explain? The error is pretty clear: there is a hardware-level issue which in turn leads to a filesystem error, which makes it so that `/dev/root` does not mount, so the init script fails because it can't run `switchroot`. The line you chose as a question title is just the very last consequence of the real error -- the init script fails, and so it, well, fails, terminates, and the kernel makes it pretty clear "Hey, init died, it wasn't supposed to happen".

Answer (score 4):

The message is quite clear: multiple SCSI errors occurred on `sda`, so `sda2` can't be mounted as your root filesystem. It's likely that you have some sort of failure in the drive that your instance is attached to, most probably that the drive is dying. The way to solve this problem is to replace the drive with a working one, and restore from your backups.

Comment: You may be able to at least temporarily recover the system by running `e2fsck -c -y` on it.  NB. that means *using another system* such as a liveCD to do it. However, this may fail miserably (if the problem is more significant than bad blocks) and if critical system files were trashed, you still won't be able to boot it, but you could at least extract files if you :( didn't back them up...

Comment: @goldilocks This is not a filesystem error in and of itself, its a filesystem error caused by a SCSI error. That won't help.

Comment: Yeah, I was not sure about that.  Oh well oh well.